# Shared service losing data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation whereby I am using a shared service function to transfer data from the first page to the second page. This is working fine, however I am having a problem when the user goes from the second page to the first. The data is being lost. I would be able to get it to work using local storage but is there another way instead?

Here is my code

first page

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerAccountDocs = this.CustomerAccountDocsService.customerAccountDocs_share;
  }
```

//click function that get's clicked on element to transfer to second page

```
  getCustomerAccountDocs(selectedItem: any, index: number) {
    this.CustomerAccountDocsService.getCustomerAccountDocs()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.CustomerAccountDocsService.customerAccountDocs_share = data._embedded.deliveryMessageList[index];  
      this.router.navigate(['/customer-account-docs']);
    });
  }
```

second page

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerAccountDocs = [this.CustomerAccountDocsService.customerAccountDocs_share];
  }
```

Shared service function

```
  customerAccountDocs_share(CustomerAccountDocs:[]) {
    return this.customerAccountDocs = CustomerAccountDocs;
  }
```

I am just passing locally stored JSON data from page to page

Comment: You can simply use an injectable class for this. I'm not sure what you are doing with the code you pasted... Just set a variable of the injectable class and use that.

Comment: On the second mage are you making this.customerAccountDocs as an array of array?

Comment: I have some logic on the first page that changes the structure so on the second page I am making it an array again. I've updated question to add this code.

Comment: Could you replicate your problem on stackblitz please, so that we can help you better>

Comment: This is a terrible idea. The second page should be in charge of loading the data it needs, and should have all it needs to do it from the route parameters (i.e. in the URL). Otherwise, refreching the second page won't be possible, bookmarking it won't be possible, open it in a new tab won't be possible, etc. etc.

Comment: but it is sensitive data?

Comment: I agree with JB. If you need the data at multiple points, and especially if it's sensitive data, you should rquest it again from your backend.

Comment: Ok, I will do this then, thanks for the suggestion.